# Причудливая сортировка по условию (больше 300 условий в запросе)

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, firebird, dataset

Есть выполненный запрос с *таблицы 1* (в *DataSet1*), в котором у каждой строки (а их более 300) есть *ID*. Строки с *ID* расположены НЕ по порядку (после сортировки пользователя).
Есть *таблица 2*, в которой строки привязаны к *таблице 1* (по *ID*), т.е. связь один ко многим.
Вопрос:
Каким образом, можно не дергая заново запрос к *таблице 1* (в *DataSet1*), выполнить выборку из *таблицы 2* (*DataSet2*), чтобы записи в *DataSet2*, были упорядочены в порядке поля *ID* (*DataSet1*). (Чтоб вывести информацию в Word, на основании результатов в двух *DataSet*).
Конструкции «*order by*» или «*union all*» не помогают, т.к. они расчитаны только до 255 параметров (столбцов результата), т.е выпадает ошибка. А у меня больше 300 строк в результате.

Можно конечно без сортировки, но тогда мне придется делать 300 циклов в *DataSet2* (чтоб соотнести строки с двух *DataSet*), это как-то не очень хотелось бы…

Comment: Нет никаких ограничений на количество строк для order by.... Вы наверно имели ввиду количество столбцов. Уточните откуда такое количество берётся, а пока формулировка вопроса крайне размыта.

Comment: ну например, вот запрос который выдает мне результат, в том прядке, который мне нужен (но он немножко длинный и не очень аккуратный): сюда не влез, поэтому дам ссылку
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2b7r6gd7yd512fa/crazy_sql.txt?dl=0

Comment: Нет, я в "order by" запихиваю все ID из DataSet1, в нужном мне порядке, поэтому такой сумасшедший "order by"

Comment: да, я тоже придумал вариант с "case" – --- select (case when DEVICE_ID_CL=473 then 1 --else null
             when DEVICE_ID_CL= 392 then 2
...           when DEVICE_ID_CL= 297 then 663 else null end) FIELD_SORT,
DEVICE_ID_CL, NUMBER_CERT, DATE_OPERATION, CALIBRATION_INTERVAL, DESCRIPTION
 from CERTIFICATE ...
order by FIELD_SORT --- посмотрите... (600 записей уже работает, проверял в IBExpert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем я бы подумал в сторону записать это во временную таблицу, но не знаю какой контекст у задачи. А одним запросом можете попробовать конструктор таблиц:

```
WITH UserOrderCTE (UserOrder, DEVICE_ID_CL) AS (VALUES
  (1, 100),(2,300),(3,200),(4,500),(5,400)
)

--,CERTIFICATE(DEVICE_ID_CL) AS (VALUES(100),(200),(300),(400),(500))

SELECT U.UserOrder, C.DEVICE_ID_CL 
FROM CERTIFICATE C 
  JOIN UserOrderCTE U ON C.DEVICE_ID_CL = U.DEVICE_ID_CL
ORDER BY UserOrder
```

Если раскомментировать CERTIFICATE, получится следующее:

| UserOrder | DEVICE_ID_CL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 300 |
| 3 | 200 |
| 4 | 500 |
| 5 | 400 |

Вот ещё посмотрите:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913457/how-do-i-name-columns-in-a-values-clause/62718343